# Java How to random 2 mouse position

Tags: java, mouse

My objective is to random 2 mouse click position. Currently I am able to do alternate click.
Below is my code and the position I want to do the random click. Note* , I only want to random between this 2 position.

### Code

```
 try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(rate);
                    robot.mouseMove(1749, 400);
                    System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                     Thread.sleep(rate);
                    robot.mouseMove(1655, 400);
                    System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: What are your constraints?  Default screen? Viewable desktop? Window bounds?

Comment: no constraints but I have no idea how to make it random

Comment: What is *between* here?  On the same line?

Comment: same line but 2 different point

Comment: `Math.random()` which returns a random number between 0 & 1...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure my logic work. I manage to get this working.

```
  try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
         Random random = new Random();
       int rn;

        while (true) {
         rn = random.nextInt(10-1)+1;
         int pointer = 0;
         System.out.println(rn);
         if (rn>5){
          pointer = 1749;   
         }
         else {
               pointer = 1655;   
         }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(rate);
                robot.mouseMove(pointer, 400);
                System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```